# How to pass parameters to AWS Lambda function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I know that it is possible to pass parameters to a Java program running on AWS Lambda in order to test it. But I do not know how to pass those parameters if this program gets called by a schedule event.

Does anyone know if this is possible? If yes, how?
I was not able to find anything about it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass parameters indirectly, for example by storing those on s3 or dynamo db. On each scheduled cycle, you can read from the predetermined location and pass it to your program. Normally, if I need to launch multiple scheduled lambda functions with shared source code, I bundle a file (any readable format) with the source code itself and read it during the run. 
@garnaat is right, furthermore it is currently impossible to dynamically launch new lambda functions, which is a great inconvenience.

Answer (score 10):

You could leverage the environment variables from the lambda configuration. Then you read them on your Java program with:

```
System.getenv("VAR_NAME")
```

Answer (score 10):

You can create a CloudWatch rule as a schedule and configure target's input as a constant json value:

**CloudWatch -> Events -> Rules -> Schedule -> Targers**

Set *Configure input* as **Сonstant (JSON text)** and pass any valid json-data there.

In Lambda you can access constant input as an input object.

[image: AWS CloudWatch screenshot]

Comment: Hi, after passing the custom input (say in json) how do you access the elements from the input inside the lambda? I am using Python 3.7 as the runtime. Is the input passed in the event or context or there is another object to access the elements? Ive been stuck here for quite some time help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @UmangMistry Hi! My function handler in .net looks like this: public async Task FunctionHandler(Request request, ILambdaContext context) where Request is just a class that serializes its fields with JsonProperty - so basically input is a json value. I believe it corresponds to event in py handler def my_handler(event, context)

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you have automated deploys or CI, is to insert your arguments on build time with maven(or similar) and properties.
I guess it's a little more optimized as you don't have to read a file from S3?

For example you can have `config/env1/app.properties` and `config/env2/app.properties`

The with maven you create profiles that load the respective config like:

```
...
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>env1</id>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>config/env1</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>env2</id>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>config/env2</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
...
```

In your code read the props as usual `props.load(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("app.properties"));`

In your automation you can build `mvn install -P en1` to get your Jar to deploy.

Answer (score -2):

Currently, the only way to create a scheduled Lambda function is via the AWS Console and it does not provide any way to pass parameters to the Lambda function when the scheduler calls it.  Since your Lambda function is being called by the scheduler in AWS, it's not really clear to me how parameter passing would work.